# Почему появляется ошибка при использовании tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу программу на python 3 с использованием tkinter. При запуске вылезает ошибка 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "part_manager.py", line 1, in 
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.title('Programm')
app.geometry('700x350')

app.mainloop()
```

Первый запуск прошел без ошибки, но почему то вместо запука программы компьютер перезагрузился, и больше ничего не произошло.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Система macOS mojave 10.14.6

Comment: А Python какая версия?

Comment: Python версии 3.7

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить может криво встал

Comment: Пробовал, не идет все равно, но "решил" проблему установив версию 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ситуацию запустив программу не через команду python file.py , а через через python3 file.py

Comment: Ну значит у вас 2 ветка установлена в системе

Comment: Вы можете запустить свой пример как пробовали поменяв строчку импорта на  from Tkinter import *

Comment: в макоси по умолчанию стоит 2 версия питона (встроенная)